# How to retrieve data from Access Web App running in Office 365 Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, ms-access-web-app

I have created an Access Web App that resides in an Office 365 Sharepoint 2013 site.  This site is hosted by microsoft (user@domain.onmicrosoft.com).  The Access Web App uses an in-house SQL Server database for the data source.  The problem is that any changes to the data within the App are stored on Sharepoint database, and do not make it back to the in-house SQL Server database.  I can see the connection information to the Sharepoint database.

[image]

My question is what is the best way to get that data back to our in-house SQL Server database?  I'd prefer the Web App could save the data directly back to our in-house database, but that doesn't seem to be possible.  Can I create a Linked Server in the in-house SQL Server to pull the data and refresh it every X minutes?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Database Synchronization?

If so, I recommend you using the [Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx).

And [SSIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx) could also be an option